# Bypassing Role ID for Discord Bot

Tags: discord

so I created small bot for Discord in Java but I want to use it on multiple Discord Servers but thats not possible because of Role ID so how could I bypass role ID? Thank you

```
const Role =  Role ID


})

bot.on('message', message=>{
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.content === '$register'){
        message.member.roles.add(Registred);
        message.channel.send('Congrats.You are now registered!');
    }

});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are using javascript for this bot. And if you don't want to check the role by id then use the name of the role

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I didnt even came to that idea xD Thank you!!

Comment: But I have one more question maybe you can help me. Bot works only on one server not on multiple. Do you know maybe why? Thank you.